# How does the Electro Pulse work?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

The MEC-mountable Electro Pulse is supposed to stun organic enemies and damage robotic enemies in an area around the MEC trooper. What exactly does it do? How much damage does it do to robots? How many turns are organic enemies stunned for? Are organic enemies completely incapacitated by stun? What is the ability's radius? How many charges does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Source](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Electro_Pulse), "Electro Pulse is an Area of Effect ability that deals 5 damage to all units (excluding the MEC) within its radius. Robotic enemies are stunned for one turn."

It does 5 damage to all units (including allies but excluding the MEC using this ability in the sphere area around the MEC), then it stuns as well Robotic units for 1 turn. Here's a picture of affected tiles.

[image]

Comment: Which tiles around the user does it affect? What does stun mean? Why are you saying the same thing twice?

Comment: It affect units in a sphere around the unit, I cannot remember on the top of my head if it is 3 or 2 tiles around the unit, the wiki does not mention this.

Comment: @kotekzot: thanks for adding the picture, what tool did you use to make it ?

Comment: No probs. Paint.NET.

Answer (score 1):

think of this as a rocket that is centered on your mech as far as area effect.
If your plan, like mine was to get set up with paladins and then stun enemies for research, think again. they KILL organic enemies, NOT stun them, game description is junk.

the one good thing about this is it does not count as explosive so you get to keep the loot.